# Edit Web2py json output for Google Chart

Tags: json, web2py

I have managed to get the google charts plugin (http://www.web2pyslices.com/slice/show/1721/google-charts-plugin) to work with my web2py application.  Using the JSON example data (data hard coded into default.py).

I am struggling with using my own data.  The chart does not work with my JSON data which returns the information as:

```
{"data": [["2014-03-28", 1000], ["2014-03-25", 1100]]}
```

When I hardcode the data with the titles, the chart works:

```
data = [['Date','Sales'],["2014-03-28",1000],["2014-03-25",1100]]
```

This returns JSON as:

```
{"data": [["Date", "Sales"], ["2014-03-28", 1000], ["2014-03-25", 1100]]}
```

The code for this is:

```
def return_data():
data = [['Date','Sales'],["2014-03-28",1000],["2014-03-25",1100]]
return dict(data=data)
```

Below is the code I am using in default.py to return the information from the database, the query works, it's the chart that doesn't!:

```
def return_data():    
sales = db().select(db.sales.quantity, db.sales.date)
data = [[row.date,row.quantity] for row in sales]
return dict(data=data)
```

Somehow, I think I need to add the 'date' and 'sales' labels to the start of the json data but I have not managed to do this - I think I need to do some sort of encode? - do I need to use the simplejson or can this be done without??

Many thanks

Comment: Can you just insert them to the list? That is, after your list comprehension, add this line: `data.insert(0, ['Date', 'Sales'])`

Comment: ah excellent - that has worked! Thank you very much! If anyone knows how to do this by changing the JSON using the filterin / encode(??) I would really appreciate understanding how though.